# Access HTML Input element in core.cljs Clojure Script

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I have the following code in my core.cljs file.
I want to access the value of input element.

```
[:input {:type "text" :id "input_id"}]
[:button {:onClick
            (fn [e]
              (first-function "arg1" "want-value-of-input_id-here")
              (second-function "arg1"))}
 "Do things"]]
```

New to ClojureScript. Should I use om/core IRootProperties (https://cljdoc.org/d/org.omcljs/om/1.0.0-beta4/api/om.core#IRootProperties)?
Is there any other way around?

Comment: Which library/framework do you use? This doesn't look like Om? Is this reagent? re-frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Om framework was superseded by Om Next and then again by Fulcro

I think for this problem you can check in JavaScript what the structure of e is and then pull it off using JavaScript introp

I'm not near a repl but this might work:

```
(.-value e)
```

If not double check this blog post

https://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/

If that still doesn't help the Clojure community are very active and helpful on slack

Comment: Got it working with ".-value x". I accessed value from the JS document by (js/document.getElementById "input_id")